# Items per page not being honored

Tags: bug, tag-watching

On the main questions page, I select 50 items per page, but it only displays about 25-30. I don't remember the old design working this way. Also, I now see lots of questions that I don't care about--was the way "favorite tags" works changed?

Answer (score 3):

Well you have a lot of ignored tags and you have it set to hide them from the list. So if your page consists of a lot of ignored questions, yeah a lot of them will be hidden from the page and you won't have 50 questions on the page. We don't generate separate lists for each users' personalized set of favorite and ignored tags. We only apply styles to the same list everyone gets depending on your preferences.